# Stop Kodi from starting its Pulseaudio instance

Tags: pulseaudio, xbmc, mpd

I have a computer (Intel NUC) wired to my hifi (jack) and my TV (HDMI). I have multiple softwares running on it: MPD and Kodi. I need to use Pulseaudio, because I sometime stream some audio from my desktop PC to this one, to use the hifi.

To achieve this, I start Pulseaudio in daemon mode. However, Kodi keeps starting its own Pulseaudio instance, and I can't get it to connect to the daemon one. On MPD, this is how I did:

```
audio_output {
        type            "pulse"
        name            "Jack"
        mixer_type      "software"
        server          "localhost"
}
```

It works fine. However, each time Kodi tries to use my jack output, MPD can't use it. If MPD is already using it when Kodi starts, Kodi doesn't see the jack output, and uses HDMI. I tried to add this to my `/etc/pulse/client.conf`, but I think it's not used anymore (it does nothing anyway):

```
default-server = "localhost"
autospawn = no
```

Is there any way to use the system instance of Pulseaudio from Kodi?

Comment: Yes, it did nothing either. (As Kodi starts with a specific user, I added it to its home directory.)

Comment: Which PA version do you have?

Comment: 5.0, running on Archlinux. Kodi is 14.0.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted other comment to quickly.

Comment: Believe PA 5 uses `~/.config/pulse/client.conf` instead of `~/.pulse/client.conf`, but it should also read `/etc/pulse/client.conf` so unlikely it will help. Do you have: `/etc/xdg/autostart` .desktop file? ref: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Disabling_automatic_spawning_of_PulseAudio_server

Comment: Good catch, I have a `etc/xdg/autostart/pulseaudio.desktop`. I'll try to remove it and post here (I can't try right now).